# Assigning labels for different portions of the list

Tags: python, list, numpy, concatenation

I have the following list:

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

I need to simply assign the values `1,2,3` together label `0`, and `4,5,6` label `1`.

The first thing that came to my mind was [numpy.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), but didn't figure out how to use it in my case.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: are you expecting a dict like : `{0:[1,2,3],1:[4,5,6]}` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert the numpy array to a list, then gather the indices and subsists, then add them to a dictionary:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]).to_list()
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> ind = [0, 1]
>>> sublists = [a[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]
>>> sublists
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> d = dict(zip(ind, sublists))
>>> d
{0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [4, 5, 6]}
>>> d[0]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> d[1]
[4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for something like this:

```
In [30]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

In [31]: labels = np.empty(len(a))

In [32]: labels[np.in1d(a, [1,2,3])] = 0

In [33]: labels[np.in1d(a, [4,5,6])] = 1

In [34]: result = np.vstack((a, labels)).T

In [35]: result
Out[35]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  1.],
       [ 5.,  1.],
       [ 6.,  1.]])
```